# I want to print echo inside echo code

Tags: php, echo, php-printer

I am trying to modifi link in this line, can you help me?

```
/'. str_replace(' ', '+', $location).'/
```

code

this is the fals code:

```
/<?php echo  str_replace(' ', '+', <?php echo '$location';?>);?>/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can echo out the statement like so:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $siteurl.'/'.$countrySelect.'/'.str_replace(' ', '+', $location).'/'.str_replace(' ', '+', $jobSelect).'-'.$lang['seo_url1']; ?>.html"/>
```

So if your code is something like so:

```
<?php
$siteurl = "http://google.com";
$countrySelect = "india";
$location = "north india";
$jobSelect = "software engineer";
$lang['seo_url1'] = "sample_url";
?>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $siteurl.'/'.$countrySelect.'/'.str_replace(' ', '+', $location).'/'.str_replace(' ', '+', $jobSelect).'-'.$lang['seo_url1'];?>.html"/>
```

Your output will be :

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://google.com/india/north+india/software+engineer-sample_url.html"/>
```

**UPDATE**

also you should provide an icon file for shortcut icon not a html page.

Comment: Hello, thanks for quick reply. but i think we miss something: I mean i want to echo this line: /'.str_replace(' ', '+', $location).'/ I need to print it or echo it like this /<?php echo  str_replace(' ', '+', <?php echo '$location;?>').';?>/ but this is not work. i want to echo inside echo.

Comment: @AgusYuliyanto what do you expect ?

Comment: Hi, i am changing my question. this line is in the head.php to write canonical url for: <link rel=”canonical” href="<?=_siteurl ?>/<?php echo $countrySelect;?>/'. str_replace(' ', '+', $location).'/'. str_replace(' ', '+', $jobSelect).'-'<?php echo $lang['seo_url1'];?>'.html"/> I need to echo that line that not using echo( string replace), just like my question.

Comment: @AgusYuliyanto Please be more clear you are saying `I need to echo that line that not using echo` and the question says `I want to print echo inside echo code` ?

Comment: I need to make string replace to php code. with echo. not like that. please see my first post.

Comment: @AgusYuliyanto that is the only way to go about it.

Comment: is this code correct: <?php echo str_replace(' ', '+', $location);?>

Comment: @AgusYuliyanto Yes it is. it will echo out the location replacing all the spaces with +